# Why is the Cookie Header not set on my same-domain $.ajax request within phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, phantomjs

I am issueing requests within the same domain via jQuery's `$.ajax(request)` function. Unfortunately the Cookie header is never set (neither `POST` nor `GET`) and I don't know why.

If i understand jQuery Ajax correctly, the `Cookie` header should be set according to the pages cookies (like `document.cookie`). I've traced `document.cookie` and to me it seems that it is updated correctly (according to the `Set-Cookie` header) with every xhr response. But when debugging the Requests all have the `Cookie` header not set.

Simplified version of how my requests are created:

```
var request = {
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'theDataIsCorrect=true',
    async: false,
    url: '/a/relative/url/like/this?maybe=even&with=this',
    // withCredentials does not help (ignored on same domain request anyways)
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) { doStuff(); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { errorHandling(); },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { complete(); }
};
$.ajax(request);
```

How my scripts work:

1. Domain is opened in the browser (no cookies yet)
2. Login via `$.ajax` xhr Request (response has cookies)
3. Requests via `$.ajax` to pages I want to see/modify/ect. (requests miss `Cookie` header)
4. `GO TO 3.` || `GO TO 5.`
5. Logout via `$.ajax`

EDIT:

I am using `phantomjs` [1.9] as browser. This problem does not occur when using Firefox or Chrome. I've found this question, where someone is describing a similar behaviour: [phantomjs - Cookie is not being sent for any XHR/POST/GET AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953864/phantomjs-cookie-is-not-being-sent-for-any-xhr-post-get-ajax-requests)

Comment: Linkception: check your link to the other question.

Comment: Are you running phantomjs with `--cookies-file=x` as the first parameter on the command line?

Comment: Why you use javascript to send Ajax request? Use phantomJS to send ajax request to the server, and this way your cookies will be sent. If you prefer to send Ajax request using javascript, then set your cookies in Ajax javascript request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851896/how-to-set-cookie-value-with-ajax-request

Comment: The same thing was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953864/phantomjs-cookie-is-not-being-sent-for-any-xhr-post-get-ajax-requests